# Swapping value in linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

i want to sort inside a linked list, changing a value between nodes without messing the address, when i put the condition for swapping, i cant put any codes there. I tried inserting printf and changing the values (beside swap) and its resulted in error.

i want to know which part is wrong on my codes and how can i fix this without changing too much on the structure, this code is experimented based on what i learned, thanks in Advance guys

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct Nodes
    {
        int value;
        Nodes* next,*prev;
        Nodes(int val)
        {
            value = val;
            next = prev = NULL;
        }
    }Nodes;
    Nodes *head,*tail,*curr;

    void display()
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr)
        {
            printf("%d ",curr->value);
            curr=curr->next;
        }
    }

    void swap(Nodes *a,Nodes *b)
    {
        int temp = a->value;
        a->value = b->value;
        b->value = temp;
    }
    void sort()
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr)
        {
            Nodes *next = curr->next;
            if(curr->value > next->value && next != NULL)
            {
    //          this space cant code anything or it will break
    //          swap(curr,next);
            }
            curr = next;
        }
    }

    void insert(int val)
    {
        if(!head)
        {
            head = tail = new Nodes(val);
        }
        else
        {
            curr = new Nodes(val);
            tail->next = curr;
            curr->prev = tail;
            tail = curr;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        insert(8);
        insert(3);
        insert(20);
        display();
        puts("");
        sort();
        display();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Or, @H.S , assume the language tag is wrong. You cannot "mix" C and C++ code; it's either C or C++. And as it seems to compile Occam's Razor says it's C++ with C **coding style**.

Comment: "you cannot mix" - at least not in the same compilation unit...

Comment: "it's resulted in error" - which kind of error?

Comment: @Aconcagua the display in the later stage doesnt show nad return value is over million

Comment: i dont know which part of it is C++, but i did tried to change the  = new Nodes() to malloc() but still doesnt work... any suggestion about which i should change ?

Comment: @Kenny: Exactly: `new` is C++; additionally, you have provided a constructor, C does not know constructors nor any other *member* functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(curr->value > next->value && next != NULL)
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^   too late!
```

`a && b` checks first a and only if a is true, b is evaluated at all – so the check for `next` being `nullptr` is only evaluated after *already having* accessed `*next` (if at all, program likely has crashed before if `next` *is* `nullptr`). So check the other way round:

```
if(next && curr->value > next->value)
```

Then your sorting algorithm is incomplete, looks very much like bubble sort, but only one single "bubble" rises...

Comment: Wow really thanks dude, you help me so much, never though such basic would really be impactful